# update mysql table with same row but different cell names

Tags: php, sql

how i can update mysql table with php?

example

i have:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET numbers = 'null' where no = '1'") or die(mysql_error());
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET numbers = 'null' where no = '2'") or die(mysql_error());
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET numbers = 'null' where no = '3'") or die(mysql_error());
```

i need one mysql request, i try this example but it doesn't work.

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET numbers = 'null' WHERE no IN ('1, 2, 3')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `'null'` is a string with the letters `n`, `u`, `l`, and `l` in it. If you're trying to null out that field with an SQL null, then it should be just `null`, without quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the single quotes around your `WHERE no IN ('1, 2, 3')` it will fix your problem

This is assuming that your no column is an integer column

Answer (score 1):

The solution you have come up with only has one item in the `IN`, and so would be equivalent to:

```
UPDATE table_name SET numbers = 'null' WHERE no = '1, 2, 3'
```

You need to use separate strings for each value, i.e.:

```
UPDATE table_name SET numbers = 'null' WHERE no IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

Comment: Did it error, or not make a change? I only ask because it's identical in form to the examples you gave in the question, and if the examples in the question worked then this should have done too.

Comment: yes, showing mysql error.
this solution helps:
UPDATE table_name SET numbers = 'null' where no IN (1,2,3)

Comment: @toritumae Considering that your original examples treated `no` as a string and worked ok, that's a bit odd. Thanks anyway.